# How to select all children elements when hovered over a children element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to replicate this effect when you hover over a text, all other texts will get opacity 0.

Here's the site: https://www.jeandawson.com/

I tried to approach this problem with pure css. However, to my knowledge, you can't select all the children when you hover a particular child and affect them.

I tried it with a `~` selector which just works partially because it sets the opacity to upcoming children but the previous are unaffected.

I tried this code with a javascript, but the value in a selectedBox won't get saved when I hover it and the opacity won't change. I am still learning javascript and I believe that with event listener the code won't change?

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=box-]")
let selectedBox  = null

const newList = [...boxes]

boxes.forEach( (e) => {

    e.addEventListener("mouseover", () =>{
      selectedBox = e
      
    })

    e.addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=>{
        selectedBox = null
    })

})

console.log(selectedBox)


boxes.forEach( (e) => {

   if (selectedBox == null){
     e.style.opacity = 1
   }
   else{
     e.style.opacity = 0
   }
})
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: serif;
}



[class^="box-"] {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.container:hover [class^="box-"]:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.box-1 {
  grid-area: A;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-2 {
  grid-area: B;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-3 {
  grid-area: C;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-4 {
  grid-area: D;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.box-5 {
  grid-area: E;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-6 {
  grid-area: F;
  align-self: center;
}

.box-7 {
  
  grid-area: G;
 
  align-self: center;
}

.container4 {
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-areas: "A A A B    B B D D   D C C C" "A A A B    B B D D   D C C C" "E E E F    F F . .   . G G G" "E E E F    F F . .   . G G G";
}

@media (max-width: 996px) {
  .container4 {
    grid-template-areas: "A A" "B B" "C D" "C D" "E E" "F F";
  }
}

@media (max-width: 556px) {
  .container4 {
    grid-template-areas: "A" "B" "D" "D" "D" "C" "E" "F";
  }
}

.changing {
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: red;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="container4">
  <div class="box-1">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <p>Starface*</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-3">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-4">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-5">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-6">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-7">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When hovering over a box, should all other boxes hide, except for the current one?

Comment: That's right! But I mean all even the children that are behind the selected child

Comment: @Spreceriany I have added an answer, Is that what you want?

Comment: You can do the first part - hiding all the boxes except the one hovered - using pure CSS. But you need Javascript to sense when a box is unhovered (mouseout) so that all the other boxes can be reset to opacity 1 even though the container might still be being hovered over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How does it work?

---

1. First we make a loop, which has the current as `i`. With the help of it, we add 2 events to each `box`(`boxes[i]`) like this:

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
     boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {

     });

     boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {

     });
   }
   ```

2. Now we add another loop, which has the current as `j` inside the `mouseover` event. We added another loop because we did not want to select the already hovered element so we use `i !== j` in an if-else statement: *(here already selected is `i` and `j` also has the same element `i` in it that is why we excluded it with this `i !== j`)* And then we simply added `opacity` of `0` to all which are not hovered and the one which is hovered has a `opacity` of `1`

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
     boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
       for (let j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
         if (i !== j) boxes[j].style.opacity = 0;
         else boxes[j].style.opacity = 1;
       }
     });

    . . .
   }
   ```

3. And at last we add `opacity` of `1` to all as the as the hovered is left.

   ```
     . . .

     boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
       for (let j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
         boxes[j].style.opacity = 1;
       }
     });
   }
   ```

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=box-]");

for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    for (let j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
      if (i !== j) boxes[j].style.opacity = 0;
      else boxes[j].style.opacity = 1;
    }
  });

  boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    for (let j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
      boxes[j].style.opacity = 1;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: serif;
}

[class^="box-"] {
  background-color: skyblue;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

[class^="box-"]:hover {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container:hover [class^="box-"]:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.box-1 {
  grid-area: A;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-2 {
  grid-area: B;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-3 {
  grid-area: C;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-4 {
  grid-area: D;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.box-5 {
  grid-area: E;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-6 {
  grid-area: F;
  align-self: center;
}

.box-7 {
  grid-area: G;
  align-self: center;
}

.container4 {
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-areas: "A A A B    B B D D   D C C C" "A A A B    B B D D   D C C C" "E E E F    F F . .   . G G G" "E E E F    F F . .   . G G G";
}

@media (max-width: 996px) {
  .container4 {
    grid-template-areas: "A A" "B B" "C D" "C D" "E E" "F F";
  }
}

@media (max-width: 556px) {
  .container4 {
    grid-template-areas: "A" "B" "D" "D" "D" "C" "E" "F";
  }
}

.changing {
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container4">
  <div class="box-1">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <p>Starface*</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-3">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-4">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-5">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-6">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-7">
    <p>Devilish</p>
    <p>00:01:34</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### [Check it out on Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/PoWGwKJ)

---

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Can you elaborate more on how you approached this problem and why did you created an even listener for each of the block as well as the second loop?

Comment: @Spreceriany I am adding the explanation...✌

Comment: @Spreceriany I have added the explanation, If you did not understand anything let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `forEach()` method.

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=box-]");

boxes.forEach(function(box) {
    box.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        boxes.forEach(function(box_hide) {box_hide.style.opacity = '0'});       
        this.style.opacity = '';
    })    
    box.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        boxes.forEach(function(box_show) {box_show.style.opacity = ''});
    })
});
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-family: serif;
}

[class^="box-"] {
    background-color: skyblue;
    transition: .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*.container:hover [class^="box-"]:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0;
}*/

.box-1 {
    grid-area: A;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-2 {
    grid-area: B;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-3 {
    grid-area: C;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-4 {
    grid-area: D;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.box-5 {
    grid-area: E;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.box-6 {
    grid-area: F;
    align-self: center;
}

.box-7 {
    grid-area: G;

    align-self: center;
}

.container4 {
    margin-top: 3em;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-template-areas: "A A A B    B B D D   D C C C" "A A A B    B B D D   D C C C" "E E E F    F F . .   . G G G" "E E E F    F F . .   . G G G";
}

@media (max-width: 996px) {
    .container4 {
        grid-template-areas: "A A" "B B" "C D" "C D" "E E" "F F";
    }
}

@media (max-width: 556px) {
    .container4 {
        grid-template-areas: "A" "B" "D" "D" "D" "C" "E" "F";
    }
}

.changing {
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: red;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="container4">
    <div class="box-1">
        <p>Devilish</p>
        <p>00:01:34</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
        <p>Starface*</p>
        <p>00:01:34</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3">
        <p>Devilish</p>
        <p>00:01:34</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-4">
        <p>Devilish</p>
        <p>00:01:34</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-5">
        <p>Devilish</p>
        <p>00:01:34</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-6">
        <p>Devilish</p>
        <p>00:01:34</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-7">
        <p>Devilish</p>
        <p>00:01:34</p>
    </div>
</div>
```